# Connection between Tehillim 68 and the Song of Deborah?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, tehilim-psalms, shoftim--book-of, devorah

I've noticed a number of similarities between the language of Tehillim 68 and the Song of Deborah (Shofetim 5).

Some examples:

[Tehillim 68:8-9](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.68.8?lang=bi):

> **אֱ‍ֽלֹהִ֗ים בְּ֭צֵאתְךָ** לִפְנֵ֣י עַמֶּ֑ךָ **בְּצַעְדְּךָ֖** בִֽישִׁימ֣וֹן סֶֽלָה׃ **אֶ֤רֶץ רָעָ֨שָׁה ׀ אַף־שָׁמַ֣יִם נָטְפוּ֮ מִפְּנֵ֪י אֱלֹ֫הִ֥ים זֶ֥ה סִינַ֑י מִפְּנֵ֥י אֱ֝לֹהִ֗ים אֱלֹהֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל**׃
>
> **O God, when You went forth** at the head of Your army, **when You marched** through the desert, selah **the earth trembled, the sky rained because of God, yon Sinai, because of God, the God of Israel**.

[Shofetim 5:4-5](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.5.4?lang=bi):

> **יְהוָ֗ה בְּצֵאתְךָ֤** מִשֵּׂעִיר֙ **בְּצַעְדְּךָ֙** מִשְּׂדֵ֣ה אֱד֔וֹם **אֶ֣רֶץ רָעָ֔שָׁה גַּם־שָׁמַ֖יִם נָטָ֑פוּ** גַּם־עָבִ֖ים נָ֥טְפוּ מָֽיִם׃ הָרִ֥ים נָזְל֖וּ **מִפְּנֵ֣י יְהוָ֑ה זֶ֣ה סִינַ֔י מִפְּנֵ֕י יְהוָ֖ה אֱלֹהֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל**׃
>
> **O LORD, when You came forth** from Seir, **Marched** from the country of Edom, **The earth trembled; The heavens dripped**, Yea, the clouds dripped water, The mountains quaked— **Before the LORD, Him of Sinai, Before the LORD, God of Israel**.

[Tehillim 68:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.68.14?lang=bi):

> אִֽם־תִּשְׁכְּבוּן֮ **בֵּ֪ין שְׁפַ֫תָּ֥יִם**
>
> even for those of you who lie **among the sheepfolds**

[Shofetim 5:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.5.16?lang=bi):

> לָ֣מָּה יָשַׁ֗בְתָּ **בֵּ֚ין הַֽמִּשְׁפְּתַ֔יִם**
>
> Why then did you stay **among the sheepfolds**

[Tehillim 68:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.68.22?lang=bi):

> אַךְ־אֱלֹהִ֗ים **יִמְחַץ֮ רֹ֤אשׁ** אֹ֫יְבָ֥יו
>
> God will **smash the heads** of His enemies

[Shofetim 5:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.5.26?lang=bi):

> מָחֲקָ֣ה **רֹאשׁ֔וֹ וּמָחֲצָ֥ה** וְחָלְפָ֖ה רַקָּתֽוֹ
>
> She crushed **his head, Smashed** and pierced his temple.

Do any *midrashim* / classical or modern commentaries / academic scholars note this connection? What is the reason for it?

Comment: There is an article [Jewish Bible Quarterly, Vol. 40, No. 4, October-December 2012](https://www.questia.com/library/journal/1G1-302403180/psalm-68-echoes-of-the-song-of-deborah)  that deals with the issue.

Comment: The link that @AvrohomYitzchok provided was longer available, here is another one: https://jbqnew.jewishbible.org/assets/Uploads/404/jbq_404_.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rabbi Yehoshua Inbal](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A2_%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%9C) in his essay in Hebrew "[שחזור קטע מספר הישר](http://asif.co.il/download/kitvey-et/pshtot/pstot-4/3_3.pdf)" (The Restoration of a Segment from Sefer Hayashar) believed that verses such as these (from Shoftim 5 and Tehillim 68), and from other places all over Tanach, are quotes or paraphrases from the now-lost Sefer Hayashar, which according to him, may have been a compilation of ancient songs and poems written about the greatness of Hashem and was still around during the time of the prophets (see [Yehoshua 10:13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Joshua.10.13?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [Shmuel 2:1:18](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Samuel.1.18?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)). Various prophets included portions of it in their writings, copied phrases and expressions, etc. For this reason, parallels can be found between certain verses in Tanach (he made a whole table collecting all of these verses). He further theorized that the similar verses could be put together to re-form one of these ancient songs.

Answer (score 0):

*Daat Mikra* noticed the 1st and 2nd similarities.

About the first similarity, *Daat Mikra* says that both talk about the showing of the divine presence (also, see Deuteronomy 33:2 and Habakkuk 3:3 !!)

About the second and third, it's just the word for sheepfolds or smashing, and no additional connection is hidden here.